# Cómo puedo cambiar las etiquetas de acciones que se despliega, al marcar un texto que se encuentra dentro de un text input en react native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Llevo varias horas investigando cómo cambiar las etiquetas de esas acciones del inglés al español, estaría muy agradecido si me pueden ayudar con éste problema, o si me pueden facilitar el nombre de ese componente.[image: La captura de pantalla adjuntada es desde un Iphone.].

Comment: El término es "Localizations". Tienes agregado español en tu proyecto de Xcode?

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, efectivamente faltaba agregar el idioma desde el xCode. Ya lo he podido solucionar.

Answer (score 0):

Voy a extender el comentario por si otro usuario tiene el mismo inconveniente.

El término es **Localizations** y se utiliza para tener la App en diferentes idiomas. Para este ejemplo utilizaré Xcode:

1. Creamos un nuevo archivo en File -> New -> File...
2. Seleccionamos Strings File. **Importante:** Crear el archivo con nombre `Localizable.strings`.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
3. Seleccionamos el nuevo archivo creado y en la parte derecha hay la opción para Localizar.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
4. Escogemos el idioma base.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
5. Ahora aparecen las opciones para seleccionar los idiomas que va a tener la App.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
6. El archivo `Localizable.strings` ahora tiene esta estructura.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con estos archivos puedes colocar las etiquetas y las traducciones a los idiomas seleccionados.

**Localizable Español**

```
"hola": "Hola";
```

**Localizable Inglés**

```
"hola": "Hello";
```

En el código puedes utilizar las etiquetas y agregar los valores a los botones, labels, etc. de la siguiente manera:

```
self.label.text = NSLocalizedString("hola", comment: "")
```

Puedes revisar el funcionamiento cambiando el idioma del iPhone y se mostrará la traducción que hayas ingresado.

**Importante:** Para el caso de las acciones como las de la pregunta (Corta, Copiar, Pegar) solo es necesario seleccionar el `Storyboard` y Localizar ese archivo.

Comment: te agradezco mucho que hayas compartido este aporte. Saludos!